# Can't load local file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

So I will preface this by saying that I'm not all that skilled in MySQL (or regular SQL for that matter), but I'm trying to load data from a .txt file into my table that I keep for ticket sales. When I do that using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/presales1.txt' INTO TABLE presales
```

I get the `'>` prompter. And I have no idea what to do. I tried looking up solutions and the one I thought would work was:
`--local-infile[=1];` because that is straight out the MySQL handbook. It didn't work (nor did any variation on it...such as `local-infile=1;`, `local-infile=1` etc....)

Did I miss a simple step? My version of MySQL is 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Watch carefully, everything is up my sleeve.

```
mysql> SELECT 'abc
    '> 
    '> 
    '> def';
+-----------+
| abc


def |
+-----------+
| abc


def |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Notice that my first line has a quote, but not the matching quote.  When I hit return; it prompted me with `'>` -- That's the clue that I need to balance the quotes.  Eventually, I did so, and the query terminated.

Look around, I suspect there is a stray quote on the preceding or following line.  Or the quotes around the filename aren't really the same.

Comment: OK....so I figured you were referring to syntax (not sure syntactically what I did wrong still) and separated my commands like this: <br /> `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/path/presales1.txt'` <br /> `INTO TABLE presales;` <br /> And no longer got the prompt. Instead, it terminated with a file/path does not exist error....even though I know the path is true because all I did was copy it straight from Windows Explorer. So I still have the issue, just different error message.

Comment: Either turn backslashes into forward, or double them up.